# unable to addsign for rpm

Tags: linux, repository, ubuntu-18.04, rpm

I generated

```
gpg --gen-key
```

and downloaded repo to create a local repository. I am trying to

```
rpm --addsign <path to rpm file>
```

Example:

```
rpm --addsign foo.rpm
foo.rpm:
error: Could not exec gpg: No such file or directory
```

when I checked:

```
# rpm --checksig foo.rpm 
foo.rpm: digests SIGNATURES NOT OK
```

I am pretty sure that I have followed the procedure correctly, but not sure why is it showing this.

Can anyone suggest?

Regards,
Tayto

Answer (score 1):

Something on your machine is non-standard.

You can put in your `~/.rpmmacros` file:

```
%_signature gpg
%_gpg_path /home/foo/.gnupg
%_gpg_name Your Company
%_gpgbin /usr/bin/gpg2
%__gpg_sign_cmd %{__gpg} gpg --force-v3-sigs --batch --verbose --no-armor --passphrase-fd 3 --no-secmem-warning -u "%{_gpg_name}" -sbo %{__signature_filename} --digest-algo sha256 %{__plaintext_filename}'
```

You probably need only one of those lines. I would bet on `%_gpg_path`, but it can  be any other, which needs to be altered.

And do not forget to:

```
rpm --import your.public.gpg
```

Otherwise `--checksig` will not work.

Comment: When I do locate your.public.gpg, I get a lot of gpg keys. Which one is it?

Comment: gpg --list-public-keys ; gpg --armor --export ID_OF_KEY

Comment: Thank you, I exported my public key and again did rmp --checksig and got:  rpm --checksig foo.rpm
foo.rpm: digests SIGNATURES NOT OK

Comment: ```#rpm --addsign /home/Tayto/Desktop/repo/foo.rpm``` Error that I get is 
```/home/Tayto/Desktop/repo/foo.rpm:
error: Could not exec gpg: No such file or directory```

Comment: RPM tries to exucete /usr/bin/gpg, but it does not exists. Modify the variable `%_gpgbin` using the guide in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time @msuchy. Could it be because it is Ubuntu 18.04 and not under redhat?

Comment: It is definitely reason why it does not work by default. But you can tune it by those variables.

Comment: I needed to install `gpg2` to get this to work on Ubuntu.